# Wordpress Can not create directory

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to upload a new theme to my WordPress site
I get an error "Can not create directory"

Im sure its permissions errors however I cannot figure out what to do.

I have setup a new server (CentOS), I have all the ports open needed for FTP.

I can ftp from a different location through telnet.

My ftp user has full permissions to the directory.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [File Permissions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress#File_Permissions) section of [Hardening WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress):

> All files should be owned by your user account, and should be writable by you. Any file that needs write access from WordPress should be writable by the web server, if your hosting set up requires it, that may mean those files need to be group-owned by the user account used by the web server process.
>
> `/`
>
> The root WordPress directory: all files should be writable only by your user account, except .htaccess if you want WordPress to automatically generate rewrite rules for you.
>
> `/wp-admin/`
>
> The WordPress administration area: all files should be writable only by your user account.
>
> `/wp-includes/`
>
> The bulk of WordPress application logic: all files should be writable only by your user account.
>
> `/wp-content/`
>
> User-supplied content: intended to be writable by your user account and the web server process.
>
> Within `/wp-content/` you will find:
>
> `/wp-content/themes/`
>
> Theme files. If you want to use the built-in theme editor, all files need to be writable by the web server process. If you do not want to use the built-in theme editor, all files can be writable only by your user account.
>
> `/wp-content/plugins/`
>
> Plugin files: all files should be writable only by your user account.

You wouldn't go wrong by reading the entire [Hardening WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress#File_Permissions) page, really.